# Jquery autosuggest not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hey guys, I'm using jQuery's autosuggest plugin by using php to get the data. But it doesn't seem to work since I always get: No Results Found, even though I'm sure there are results:

Here's the php code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$input = mysql_escape_string($_GET["q"]);
$data = array();
$mysql=mysql_connect('localhost','***','***');
mysql_select_db('jmtdy');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%".$input."%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$json = array();
$json['value'] = $row['id'];
$json['name'] = $row['username'];
$data[] = $json;
}
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

And the script:

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#suggestedfriend").autoSuggest("suggestedf.php");
});





</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the generated GET request and response using firebug or similar?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script >  
  $(document).ready(function () {  
      $("#suggestedfriend").autoSuggest(
           "suggestedf.php",
           {
                selectedValuesProp: "value",
                selectedItemProp: "name",
                searchObjProps: "name"
           });
  });
</script>
```

Add the above parameters, it will start to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Just look at data, that server sends you back. If you use firefox you can watch it in network tab of firebug, or if you use chrome see it in resources.

Comment: I get the correct reply with the correct user information, but it always displays No Results Found!

Comment: This is the response I get: [{"value":"1","name":"samaniac"}]

Comment: I can't help you but i'm curious, is is in UI as autocomplete? or is built in JQuery? In addition, in autocomplete, data source must be something like ['term one','term two',....,'last term']

Answer (score 0):

The header must be in top of the file, right after the

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

include_once 'resources/dbconn.php';

$term = $_REQUEST['term'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM cds WHERE titel LIKE '%$term%'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$arr = array();
while ($obj = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

//for jsonp echo '('.json_encode($arr).')';
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The JS/jQuery string

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        var cache = {},
            lastXhr;
        $("#exercise").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function(request, response) {
                var term = request.term;
                if (term in cache) {
                    response(cache[term]);
                    return;
                }
                lastXhr = $.getJSON("json_Search.php", request, function(data,status,xhr) {
                    cache[term] = data;
                    if (xhr === lastXhr) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```