# AutoSuggest jQuery Plugin - No Results Found

Tags: autosuggest

I am using AutoSuggest V1.4 in my project with jquery 1.10.2. 
I can successfully add two items and when I start typing to search for the third item it tells me No Results Found. Results exists for sure. 
I can still add elements by using the tab/comma.

Is anyone having the same issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878056/jquery-autosuggest-not-working . I tried first answer. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You must clear the hidden input class "as_values" in order to fix the problem. At least, thats how I fixed it.

After submission, do this in your js file:

`$("[your container]").find(".as-values").each(function(){
$(this).val("");
});`